# How to search files with multiple extensions in a specific path using python

Tags: python, read-write

I have written a small python code to read specific files containing *.txt from the specific path. I would like to do the same thing to search for files with multiple extensions more or less with the same code with little modifications. Ofcourse, I am not looking for /* which will search all the extensions. Any help would be appreciated.

```
varlogpath = "C:/Users/vveldand/Office/Fetcher/Projects/LOG-PARSER/var/log/*.txt"

outputfile = open(wrfilename, "a")
files=glob.glob(varlogpath)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by multiple extensions?

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
files=None
# put file extensions into a list
fileext=[".txt",".log",".csv"]

for ext in fileext:
    varlogpath = "C:/Users/vveldand/Office/Fetcher/Projects/LOG-
    PARSER/var/log/*"+ext

    outputfile = open(wrfilename, "a")
    files=glob.glob(varlogpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wrfilename = os.path.join(wrscriptpath, 'TiC_Timeline_Report.txt')
varlogpath = "C:/Users/vveldand/Office/Fetcher/Projects/LOG-PARSER/var/log/*.txt"

outputfile = open(wrfilename, "a")
files=[glob.glob(varlogpath.replace(".txt",ext)) for ext in list_of_extensions_you_want_to_search]
```